# Firefox password recovery in 2016

Tags: passwords, firefox

Hi everyone,

I would like to see my passwords saved for firefox using a C++ application. I did a bit of reading and no solution was conclusive:

I found that the passwords are stored in 2 files: logins.json and key3.db (I also found a third file, cert8.db, on one site without any mention of it anywhere else).

I found that the encryption algorithm firefox uses is 3des, and that if no password is specified, an empty, 0-char password was used.

I found that the key in the logins.json file is the one encrypted with 3des and encoded with b64. The key for the encryption was stored in key3.db and one was useless without the other.

I found that I cannot read key3.db with sqlite3.dll, MySQL on XAMPP, or any other method I know of reading sql databases.

I found that although most b64 strings have a '=' char at the end, the ones in my logins.json (a single password setup just for this research) did not. Putting it through the b64 decoder in NP++ returns garbage (if its 3des encrypted not surprising) but any online decoder I used returns nothing.

I found no sources dating to 2016.

Any source code that I found to this purpose did not compile and/or was full of errors. When I removed the errors as best I could it had issues preparing the database.

Is there any information I am missing, or that is incorrect? I am truly lost here and I would appreciate it if someone were to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: You'd probably want to look at the Firefox source code.

Comment: Have you looked at how Firefox itself reads the passwords? The code for that is available, after all

Comment: Can you try decoding b64 using this tool at https://github.com/func0d3r/java_base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is open source, just go through the source. Probably the db is initialized using a password. There is a 'dbtest.c' file inside firefox source, Have a look at that file.

Also use the [NSS tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Reference/NSS_tools_:_pk12util). may be it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the following C project: https://github.com/philsmd/pswRecovery4Moz
It is older but still shows how to get the important data from the key3.db file.

Comment: This worked like a charm on a SeaMonkey profile on Linux!